# Spark's mapPartition is causing skew among worker's data distribution. Is there a way to map data partition on workers based on partition size?

Tags: java, apache-spark

My partitioned data looks like the following

```
+---+-------+
|tag|count  |
+---+-------+
|29 |240    |
|22 |9941280|
|27 |360    |
|26 |900    |
|23 |1941286|
|25 |32939  |
|24 |300148 |
+---+-------+
```

where I have partitioned the row according to their `tag` column. Now I am using `mapPartition` to process the partitioned data parallelly.
My setup contains 3 worker nodes and 1 master. I expected the partitions will be distributed among the workers so that each have approximately the same amount of data.

But when I check the logs I saw the following:

worker: 1

```
Partition Quartets Count: 1941286
Partition Quartets Count: 9941280
```

worker: 2

```
Partition Quartets Count: 360
Partition Quartets Count: 300148
```

worker: 3

```
Partition Quartets Count: 240
Partition Quartets Count: 900
Partition Quartets Count: 32939
```

Clearly, Apache Spark is distributing the partitions based on partition count, not partition size. Obviously, a better mapping would be something like: `| 9941280 | 1941286 | 300148+32939+240+360+900 |`

Is there any way of enforcing this?

Comment: Could you repartition before? You could repartition on a different column or event create one...